# Volume Integration of Bounded Region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I'm trying to integrate this volume in spherical and cylindrical coordinates, but having difficulty finding my bounds of integration;

I'm given the region in the first octant bounded by z = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, z = $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, y = x and y = $\sqrt{3}x$ and I need to evaluate $\iiint_V{}dV$

When proceeding to integrate with spherical and cylindrical coordinates I am not getting the right bounds such that both methods equate to the same volume?  I am definitely missing something.  Any and all advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This region seems better defined using spherical coordinates than cylindrical. We are given that the region is between two vertical planes $y=x$ and $y=\sqrt3x$, and it is between the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the upper half of the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$. From this, we can set the bounds to be:
$$ \frac\pi3 \le \theta \le \frac\pi4$$ 
from the region of angles between the two lines (arctan of root(3) is pi/3)
$$0 \le \phi \le \frac\pi4 $$from the intersection of the cone and sphere
$$0 \le r \le 1 $$from the radius of sphere

Comment: Hope this helps! If you need any clarification just ask :D

Comment: Thank you very much!  However can you help me by explaining your reasoning for the bounds of $\phi$

Comment: There's something crucial I forgot in the statement of the problem which I just added; I forgot to mention that I'm integrating in the first octant of the specified region.  That changes the bounds of integration right?

Comment: I had actually already assumed you were in the first octant by accident. Whoops! But have you learned spherical coordinates? If so, $\phi$ is the angle from the north pole in the clockwise direction that you are integrating. In order to describe the region between the cone and sphere, I am going from the north pole and then until I get the cone (intersection of cone and sphere)

Comment: If the question was not only first octant, I would also have to take into account the other region of theta. The region between the lines y = sqrt(3) and y = x in quadrant 3 in the xy coordinate plane is between two different angles. Theta being set as I did above only accounts for the first quadrant

Comment: This might be awful on my part, but when sketching the cone and sphere and graphing it online it appears as though the cone is below the sphere and the angle $\phi$ then does not begin from the north pole and instead I get $\pi \over 4$ to $\pi \over 2$ .  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: https://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/currentcourses/math291/gifstuff/parts.gif

Comment: That is the best image I could find of the cone and sphere. Phi always goes from the north pole to the south pole by default. In other words, if you were integrating a sphere region, it would go from 0 (north pole start) to pi (south pole). In this case, we have a smaller region so it goes from 0 to the intersection

Comment: It would probably really help you to look up a detailed description of spherical coordinates!

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I realize what I was foolishly doing wrong.  Thank you once again for your advice and patience!

Comment: Its totally fine! As a university student taking calc 3 right now, I understand your frustrations.